# Can we host a host websocket server in cloud as proxy/relay server to redirect websocket traffic from local network

Tags: websocket, raspberry-pi, digital-ocean, portforwarding

**[This post has been updated with a possible approach, which is added to the bottom]**

I am trying to create a web socket connection between  two devices((A). chrome in different computer and (B) a raspberry pi) in **different networks.** Thus,  i can send video data over websockets. However, I cannot port forward the network of my router to expose my local IP to the network, thus, I can't send the data right away.
Figure below explains the architechture.

[image]

Thus ,I am trying to implement a logic so that  Device A websockets the public ws of the cloud while, the cloud actually gets the data from Device B.So Device A websockets device B indirectly.
Device A<==>Cloud Server<==>Device B
The cloud could be something like a proxy or a relay websocket server.
The video feed needs to be sent in real time,
[image]

Please suggest how can i proceed with it.
Additional note, i have acquired an instance of digitalocean as  VPS, following the blog [Accessing home services from anywhere, without port forwarding!](https://jordancrawford.kiwi/home-server-without-portforward/) but not sure how to proceed.

**Update(11th Nov,2019):**

I am planning to use a websocket server on DigitalOcean instance(droplet),which would be  listening to my local IP/port of my raspberry pi.And this VPS would act as a websocket server,which would redirect the traffic.
However, I am unsure how to use the same.And need your kind suggestions.